# Dumping Data to File in .sql format

Tags: mysql

is there any way of dumping data from mysql beside this

[MYSQL] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

and if there is which one is efficient in working and why..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySQL does not support any binary or other formats for dumping data. Raw SQL is the recommended way both for exporting and importing, and is actually quite efficient when combined with Gzip as phpMyAdmin and its friends do.

You can actually enable most power scenarios with mysqldump, for example copying a database to a remote server:

```
mysqldump mydatabase > mysql -uuser -ppassword -hserver2.domain.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support any other methods. However not everyone has access to `mysqldump`. The most common way is to use PhpMyAdmin to dump database but for bigger databases it is often impossible to do using phpMyAdmin.

I could recommend [**Sypex Dumper**](https://sypex.net/en/) (free version is enough). You would be able to backup quite big databases without a problem and what's surprising this PHP script does it very quick.